# Simple SQL question

Tags: php, sql, pagination

(I couldn't make up a good title, sorry)

So I use this pagination:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];

$max = 5;

// if $page is empty, set page number to 1
if (empty($page)) $page = 1;

$limit = ($page - 1) * $max; 

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $limit, $max");

$totalres = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS tot FROM posts WHERE tid =     1"),0);    

$totalpages = ceil($totalres / $max);
?>
```

This works, but what I want is that the post with the oldest date always stays on top even if I change page. How can I do this? I know you can but I cant remember how.

Hopefully you do, thanks

Comment: Just a quick reminder, not nitpicking. Get rid of that Select *

Comment: All the data you SELECT will need to go from the database server to your PHP script.

Comment: William T Wild: You don't know that he doesn't need _all the data_ . But yeah in case you don't then I agree, get rid of that select *.

Comment: Hmmm, there was some other answer here as well, which apparently has been removed by its author because of the anonymous downvote? To bad. How is anyone supposed to learn from that...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to do a union query since what you want is really the combination of two pieces of data...

1. The oldest post
2. All of the other posts minus the oldest post adjusted for page position...

```
    select * from posts order by date DESC limit 0,1
    union
    select * from posts order by date desc limit $start,$end
```

Now adjust your values so start is either the page you want minimum 1 (if it's 0, your oldest post will show twice)